# CoreAudio call AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize returns wrong size

Tags: swift4, core-audio

I'm having problems with the call to **AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize** in CoreAudio. An OBJ-C project at [Github](https://github.com/tgunr/buster) tries to get the number of input devices and in the first call to AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize the size returned = 24 which divide by the element size of 4 results in only 6 devices and I have 11.

I rewrote the offending code in a simple Swift project and it returned the correct size of 44 which results in the 11 devices I have.

Then I created a new Swift file for the AudioHandle and set up the OBJ-C to Swift bridging only to discover the new Swift code being called returning the same incorrect size of 24.

I created two standalone projects and passed them to some friends for testing.

[OBJC](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rog7wjx4qvvlofq/AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize.zip?dl=0)

[SWIFT4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wssrv5pxvdmo42q/CAMetadata.zip?dl=0)

They reported they could not duplicate my problem.

My current code looks like this:

```
func getNumberOfDevices() -> UInt32 {
    var propertySize: UInt32 = 0

    var propertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
        mSelector: AudioObjectPropertySelector(kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices),
        mScope: AudioObjectPropertyScope(kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal),
        mElement: AudioObjectPropertyElement(kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster))

    _ = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(AudioObjectID(kAudioObjectSystemObject), &propertyAddress, 0, nil, &propertySize)

    return propertySize / UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.size)
}
```

The value of size is is returned with the value 24 instead of the correct value 44.

Any thoughts or ideas on what is going on would be appreciated.

Currently running MacOS 10.13.4 and both Xcode 10 and Xcode 9.3 have same result.

Comment: I created another Swift4 project and copied over the code I used in the ObjC version which used bridging and it is returning the same wrong value of 24. So now I have three projects: ObjC (using bridge code), Swift-1 (the sample project I posted), and Swift-2 a new Swift project. All three using the same AudioHandler code. ObjC and Swift-2 both return 24, the wrong value.

Comment: Your code looks correct. I use C to do the same thing the same way. When you iterate over the resulting AudioDeviceID's, getting the Name & UID, can you see any pattern in the devices found/not found?

Comment: It would also be very interesting to see what the output is when you use libraries like libsoundio or RtAudio.